# How to calculate cell values after a certain days range in excel?

Tags: excel, formula, calculation

Here is the table and i need to calculate the amount based upon the days.
[image: Reference table]

cell For days 8 to 14 cell A shows 10000, for days 15 to 21 cell A shows B+C and after 21 days cell A shows B+C+D. After 28 days with every passing week it should add cell D values additionally. for example after 28 days calculation should be B+C+D+D and so on.

Here is the formula I'm using.

```
=IF(AND($E$10>7,$E$10<=14),$B$10,IF(AND($E$10>14,$E$10<=21),SUM($B$10:$C$10),IF($E$10>21,SUM($B$10:$D$10),"")))
```

need help to calculate values after 4 weeks, on every passing week value of cell D should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF($E$10>21, $B$10+$C$10+(INT(($E$10-1)/7)-2)*$D$10, IF($E$10>14,$B$10+$C$10,IF($E$10>7,$B$10,0)))
```

In Excel, `IF` statement execution stops at the first logical test that returns `TRUE`, so by reversing the order of testing, we can eliminate all those `AND` functions you have in your original.

Then it's just a matter of computing the correct number of `D`'s to add onto `B` and `C`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i understand the logic.